I'm a Jamaican citizen and I’ve been out the country for 5 years
I'm a Jamaican citizen and I’ve been out the country for 5 years and I got a st.kitts passport. I was wondering if I can travel back home on a one way ticket to Jamaica with my st.kitts passport and renew my expired Jamaican passport but will they allow me or not?

Holders of a St. Kitts passport do not need a visa in order to enter Jamaica. I am unclear about how long you can stay, but it's almost certainly long enough to renew a passport. If you can prove you are a Jamaican citizen you can of course stay as long as you like.
A Jamaican citizen can also enter Jamaica using an expired Jamaican passport, and TIMATIC says airlines should accept that to get you on the plane.

Concerning your last sentence, there's also the question of whether an airline will let you board their plane if all you have is an expired passport.

@MichaelSeifert OP has a valid St Kitts passport, so this is not an issue for them.

@MichaelSeifert, DJClayworth: there are a few questions on this site with answers reporting that as a Jamaican citizen can enter Jamaica with an expired passport and that this is reflected in TIMATIC, so (1) it shouldn't be a problem to board the plane even without having a St. Kitts passport, and (2) it shouldn't matter how long a St. Kitts passport bearer can stay in Jamaica on a visa-free entry.  Even if OP does use the St. Kitts passport to enter, there should be no need to leave at any particular point because he is a Jamaican citizen.

@lambshaanxy:  True, but answers are supposed to be useful for future readers as well, including those who might have an expired passport but no St. Kitts passport.  That said, it appears that my concern was moot, since Timatic shows that an expired passport is sufficient to board the flight.

Thanks for the comments. I've updated a little.

Depending how old it is, might an airline reject an expired passport at boarding, on grounds that you no longer look like the picture? Not saying this is a problem for the questioner (5 years is nothing in terms of passport photos). Just that the future reader with a 50-year-old Jamaican passport perhaps had best not just assume the airline will let them board...

@lambshaanxy There is a question whether the crew should let him board the plane, and another question whether they will let him board the plane. They are not required to know all the laws, and if they get it wrong, there's nothing you can do. Now in St. Kitts I would expect them to know the legal situation. But let's say you try to fly Berlin to Jamaica, they might have never encountered anyone with a St Kitts passport and an invalid Jamaican passport.

@gnasher729 Doesn't matter, they'll punch it into Timatic and that will tell them St Kitts citizens don't need a visa for Jamaica.
